# How to solve this react-native error when i install drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am getting this error when installing react navigation drawer. Please help. Before installing drawer-navigator, I was using Stack-Navigator it was working just fine.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native-reanimated@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-reanimated
npm ERR!   react-native-reanimated@"~2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-reanimated@"^1.0.0" from react-navigation-drawer@2.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
npm ERR!   react-navigation-drawer@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When this happens? when you do the npm install? Or when you try to build the application? Please provide more details.

Comment: try to delete package-lock.json or use yarn to install it

Comment: @Gabriel Menezes da Silva, This happened when I tried to install Drawer Navigation by running the command "npm install react-navigation-drawer". After running this command, my cmd gave the above error.

Comment: @Francesco Clementi, how do I delete package-lock.json.

Comment: @Francesco Clementi, deleting package-lock.json didn't work as it is throwing the same error

Comment: Try to use yarn, it will solve it

Answer (score 2):

The error says that it has `react-native-reanimated` installed both at the root and as a dependency for `react-navigation-drawer`. The error seems to be a problem with peer dependencies. Try this

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

*PS* If you're not using `react-native-reanimated` you can uninstall it from root folder to fix this error.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I uninstalled it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Rohit says, the error happened because there's some conflict with react-native-reanimated@2.2.0. I also trying to install react-navigation-tabs and the error appears too.

So, to install the package retry with this command:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps react-navigation-tabs
```